# Robotlegs2 - ошибка 1009 в классе конфигурации

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

На этом форуме, только один человек отвечает в темах о as3, по этому сразу к делу.
Почему выдает ошибку 1009, разве что-то не так?

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import robotlegs.bender.bundles.mvcs.MVCSBundle;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.contextView.ContextView;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IContext;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IInjector;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.impl.Context;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Inject]
        protected var context:IContext;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            context = new Context()
            .install(MVCSBundle)
            .configure(MainConfiguration)
            .configure(new ContextView(this));
        }

    }

}

package  
{
    import controllers.PreloderControllerSrartCommand;
    import events.PreloderEvents;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.contextView.ContextView;
    import robotlegs.bender.extensions.eventCommandMap.api.IEventCommandMap;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IConfig;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.IContext;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.ILogger;
    import robotlegs.bender.framework.api.LogLevel;

    public class MainConfiguration implements IConfig
    {
        [Inject]
        protected var commandMap:IEventCommandMap;

        [Inject]
        protected var contextVeiw:ContextView;

        [inject]
        protected var context:IContext;

        [Inject]
        protected var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;

        [Inject]
        protected var logger:ILogger;

        public function configure():void
        {
            commandMap.map(Event.CHANGE, Event)
            .toCommand(PreloderControllerSrartCommand);
        }
    }

}

package controllers 
{
    public class PreloderControllerSrartCommand 
    {
        public function execute():void
        {
            trace('[PreloderControllerSrartCommand]');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: текст ошибки полностью можно?

Comment: надо весь проект смотреть, так не скажу сразу
- странно что в Main инжектится ([Inject]protected var context:IContext;) контекст, там он не может вроде как использовать [Inject]

Comment: Метод Main.init() в конце получает контекст?

Comment: пропишите так:

    private var context:IContext;
    context = new Context()
    context.install(MVCSBundle);
    context.configure(MainConfiguration);
    context.configure(new ContextView(this));

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Залил на гугл диск, ( без проверки и идентификации ) https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B1CrbeKHnnoeb1FjN3hkQ3BGbUk . Сейчас Ваш пример посмотрю, но я тоже много на гитхабе смотрел..

Comment: я его как здесь собирал https://github.com/darscan/robotlegs-demos-HelloFlash

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо Вам за очередную помощь! Все таки я разобрался в чем дело, уу меня в конфиге свойства протектед, а допустимо только паблик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инжектируем в переменные которые объявлены только как **public**!

```
[Inject]
public var commandMap:IEventCommandMap;

[Inject]
public var contextVeiw:ContextView;

[inject]
public var context:IContext;

[Inject]
public var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;

[Inject]
public var logger:ILogger;
```

И всё у вас заработает!